# WSAStringToAddress failing

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, ipv4

I'm trying to populate a sockaddr_in structure from an IPv4 string address using the following C++ code:

```
// WSAStringToAddress
struct sockaddr_in sock;

int addrSize = sizeof( struct sockaddr_in );

memset( &sock, 0, addrSize );

sock.sin_family = AF_INET;

rc = WSAStringToAddress( (LPWSTR) "192.168.0.1", 
                         AF_INET, 
                         NULL, 
                        (LPSOCKADDR) &sock, 
                        &addrSize ); 

if ( rc != 0 )
{
    rc = WSAGetLastError();

    printf( "WSAStringToAddress: error=[%d]\n", rc );
}
```

It is failing with error code 10022, which is WSAEINVAL. On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it states this error code occurs when the address family of sockaddr_in is not set to AF_INET or AF_INET6, which I have clearly done.

I'm running Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, but I'm not using the newer address conversion functions as I need backwards compatibility from Windows XP/Windows Server 2000 onwards.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem/what is wrong with my code? Any solutions you can give are appreciated :D

EDIT:
I discovered using WSAStringToAddressA allowed use of ASCII char instead of tchar

Comment: Per your recent discovery, yes, any time a Win32 API function deals with strings, there will be an ANSI (narrow) version and a wide (Unicode) version. The ANSI version has an `A` suffix and the Unicode version has a `W` suffix (for wide). But you should ***always*** call the Unicode version of the function. Windows has been fully Unicode for over a decade now. The ANSI stuff is long-obsolete and is only there for backwards-compatibility reasons. Internally, the ANSI versions of the functions convert the string to Unicode, then call the Unicode version.

Comment: Therefore, it's basically pointless to call them, *especially* when you're dealing with a string literal that can be easily converted to a wide string literal by prefixing it with an `L` (or using the `TEXT` macro, which handles this automatically). Either one of those is what you should *always* do. Forget about the fact that narrow character strings even exist. `char*` is not what you'll use for C-style strings when programming Windows, it'll always be `wchar_t*`.

Comment: This is also a good lesson in why you should never throw casts around just to shut up the compiler. The compiler is giving you an error for a reason, and it's trying to help you fix your code. By ignoring it and casting the value instead, you're effectively flipping the override switch to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing, shut up already". That's a tragedy, because the compiler is there to help you as a programmer. If it finds an error, chances are your code is wrong. And throwing in a cast won't make your code correct, it'll just postpone the error from compile-time to run-time.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your comments. Another reason I wanted to force the use of char * is for my application, I also have Linux support and I wanted one function for both. Since tchar is not available on Linux, char seemed to be the route to go... The backwards compatibility is also a concern for me as well. Internally, I have an #ifdef _WIN32 for the WSA case and use other functions for Linux, but both are taking char * and working successfully so I'm happy :D If it wasn't for cross-platform support and backwards compatibility, I'd be using the UNICODE version.

Comment: Instead of doing ```(LPWSTR)"IP address"```, do ```L"Ip address"```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WSAStringToAddress()` fails with `WSAEINVAL` when it cannot translate the requested address.  A mismatched family value is not the only way that an `WSAEINVAL` error can occur.  As @ChristianStieber stated, you are using a type-cast to pass an 8-bit `char[]` string literal where a 16-bit `wchar_t*` pointer is expected.  That is just plain wrong.  You are passing garbage to `WSAStringToAddress()`, and it is detecting that.

You need to use the `TEXT()` macro instead when passing a string literal to an `LPTSTR` value, eg:

```
rc = WSAStringToAddress( TEXT("192.168.0.1"), ... );
```

Otherwise, call the Unicode version of `WSAStringToAddress()` directly, and put an `L` prefix in front of the string literal to make it a `wchar_t[]` instead of a `char[]`, eg:

```
rc = WSAStringToAddressW( L"192.168.0.1", ... );
```

Comment: TEXT( ) worked, and switching correct answer to yours as it's more extensive.

Comment: Now in 2015, WSAStringToAddress is deprecated, so you're stuck with L"...".

Comment: Where does MSDN say that `WSAStringToAddressA()` is deprecated? In any case, `getaddrinfo()` is usually preferred nowadays, and it is more portable with other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The examples I've seen online set addrSize to sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage).

There's an example at [this link](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedInternet3b.html).

Comment: `sockaddr_storage` is used for code that supports both IPv4 and IPv6.  This example code only supports IPv4, so `sockaddr_in` is appropriate to use.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this comment doesn't say it's the only possible reason for this error.

In particular, this line strikes me:

```
(LPWSTR) "192.168.0.1",
```

You are taking an 8-bit string and just casting it to the wide version. Did you try using L"192...."?

Comment: In fact, you could just NOT cast at all, and also skip the "L", which will then call the "ANSI" version of the function. I'm not too fond of these since it depends on the codepage -- and I don't know whether all codepages are ASCII-based...

Comment: I tried without casting as I had seen in other examples... but I get a compile time error: 
error C2664: 'WSAStringToAddressW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [17]' to 'LPWSTR'
so in the meantime I'll just cast it, since it seems to be working...

Comment: Oh... ok. In that case I was probably confused, since another thing I don't use is the automatic selection of functionW() vs. functionA(). I guess you're compiling with "UNICODE" set, which is a good thing and should be kept :-) You can still take out the cast and keep the L, though. Casting always has a bad feel like "the compiler gives me an error here so I cast it away" -- it's always better to NOT cast and just do the right thing instead :-)