# WSAStringToAddress error 10022 / reading IPv6 from console argument

Tags: c, windows, sockets, client-server, winsock2

when I try to connect to my server, my client fails during the function WSAStringToAddress with the error 10022, I think the problem is that I try to get the IPv6 address from a console argument. The format of the console argument is ::1 for my localhost address.

Here is the function that fails:

```
WSAStringToAddress((LPWSTR)argv[1], AF_INET6, NULL, (SOCKADDR *)&server, &len)
```

And here code for the server and len variables:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 server;
int len = sizeof(server);
memset( &server, 0, sizeof (server));
server.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
server.sin6_port = htons(PORT);
```

Yeah I hope someone sees the mistake I made.

Comment: Can it happen that you have ordinary `main()` and not `wmain()` , and your `argv[1]` is `char*` instead of `WCHAR*`/`(LPWSTR)`, as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694312/wsastringtoaddress-failing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error 10022](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is `WSAEINVAL`, which means you passed an invalid parameter.  The problem in this case is that when compiling a Unicode program, `WSAStringToAddress` takes a **wide-character string**, and you're passing it a narrow string cast to a wide string.  The compiler error you were getting before you inserted the cast should have raised a red flag.

You have a few options:

- Change your application to be non-Unicode (**not recommended**)
- Change your `main` function to be [`wmain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bky3b5dh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead, which takes wide-character argument strings
- Explicitly use the narrow (ANSI) version by calling `WSAStringToAddressA` instead of `WSAStringToAddress`
- Convert the string from narrow to wide using [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In this particular case, I'd recommend explicitly using the `WSAStringToAddressA` function, since using the wide-character version doesn't afford any extra advantage for this function.